# I am getting the below python output as a string and i would like to have the "J" Value in the string

Tags: python-3.x

> '   [('a=123,b=3456,c=789', {'D': [b'F'], 'G': [b'H'], 'I': [b'J'], 'K': [b'L']})]'
>
> I would like to parse this string and get the J value out of it

Comment: OK, so what have *you actually done* to that end?

Comment: a=[('a=123,b=3456,c=789', {'D': [e'F'], 'G': [e'H'], 'I': [e'J'], 'K': [e'L']})]
b= a[0]
c= b[1]
d= ("e['I']:", e['I'])
output : 'I': [e'J']   struck here , No able to get all in one line code

Comment: Please [edit] the question to give a [mcve].

Comment: I am deeply confused at what you are trying to achieve here. You just answered your own question (I take it?), but I am reasonably sure that what you are doing is _not_ actually parsing a string in this way. Is this a string? Is it a list of a tuple?

Answer (score 0):

var= [('a=123,b=3456,c=789', {'D': [b'F'], 'G': [b'H'], 'I': [b'J'], 'K': [b'L']})]
out= ("var[0][1]['I']:", a[0][1]['I'])[1][0].decode("utf-8")
print (out)